# Tentando criar minha própria exceção checked Java

Tags: java, exceção, throw

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pessoal, minha dúvida é a seguinte:

No método abreArquivo, eu preciso mesmo fazer esse *try-catch*?
No meu entendimento não precisaria já que estou declarando o *throws* com a minha classe ImpossibilitadaAberturaDeArquivoException que estende de IOException.

Alguém pode me explicar porque eu não consigo fazer dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Camila Cavalcante, mesmo sendo a pergunta teórica edite a pergunta e coloque o código como texto, pois em certos dispositivos código em imagem é ilegível. Veja: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/137387

Answer (score 1):

Você não consegue fazer da forma proposta, pois o método `FileInputStream` é definido da seguinte forma:

```
public FileInputStream(String name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    this(name != null ? new File(name) : null);
}
```

Então no código que chama o método `FileInputStream` é obrigatório tratar a exceção com `try/catch` **ou** repassar a exceção explicitamente na declaração do método.

### Tratando com try/catch

```
public static void abreArquivo2(String nomeArquivo) throws ImpossibilitadaAberturaDeArquivoException {
    try {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream(nomeArquivo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ImpossibilitadaAberturaDeArquivoException (nomeArquivo, e.getCause());
    }
}
```

Você pode ajustar seu método com o try/catch para lançar a partir daí sua exceção personalizada. No seu caso, está lançando **sempre** uma exceção pois **não está usando a expressão `try/catch`**.

### Lançando para ser tratada pelo método chamador

```
public static void abreArquivo(String nomeArquivo) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(nomeArquivo);
}
```

Precisa constar `throws FileNotFoundException` se não foi tratada com o `try/catch`.

Comment: Melhor resposta não há! Muito obrigada pelo tempo dedicado em me ajudar.

Comment: Obrigado @CamilaCavalcante, que bom que ajudei. Por favor, confira [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)